# Problem using bisect percentage

Tags: python, scripting

I am currently trying to split an edge in specific places. I have tried:

```
bmesh.ops.bisect_edges(bm, edges=[bm.edges[0]], cuts=2, edge_percents={bm.edges[0]: 0.1, bm.edges[0]: 0.60})
```

While this does split the edge in two it does so evenly and does not split them at the correct locations along the edge.

Basically what I am trying to do is add new vertices up to 5 new ones along a given edge at specific points.

Comment: It does split correctly if cut =  1, so you may use this function and some of your own code to cut correctly.